# Des gens que l'on croit être « sachants » ?

Tags: sens, verbes, adjectifs, origine-ou-raison, substantivation

> En matière de prévention des infections, j’ai toujours cru naïvement
> qu’il allait de soi que des soignants soient **sachants** et hyper
> vigilants. (ds. [*LaPresse*](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/opinions/2021-02-25/travailleurs-de-la-sante/refuser-le-vaccin-est-irresponsable.php))

C'est la première fois que je rencontre le [substantif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sachant) et je ne sais pas si l'emploi dépasse le sens du [participe présent](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/savoir), ou si c'est une caractéristique ou un comportement dont on parle et quelle connotation ça pourrait avoir ; est-ce clair, qu'en pense-t-on et pourquoi ? S'agit-il d'un emploi récent ?

Comment: [Commentaire car je n'ai pas d'autres sources que mon instinct ici]. Il semblerait que cette utilisation soit spécifique au Canada. En France, ou en tout cas de ma propre expérience, le terme "sachants" comme nom ou adjectif serait employé de façon ironique et légèrement péjorative pour désigner "ceux qui savent tout", en quelque sorte les "monsieur-je-sais-tout". Par exemple : "- Le conseil scientifique recommande un confinement ! - Ah, si ce sont les *sachants* qui le disent..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En France, le terme est utilisé avec une connotation ironique/péjorative comme suggéré par Reyedy et discuté [ici](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/didier-pourquery/juste-un-mot-les-sachants_b_5842666.html), alors que d'aprés l'exemple l'utilisation semble plus neutre au Canada.

Autrement, j'ai aussi rencontré le terme dans un contexte juridique comme décrit dans la définition wiktionnaire même s'il n'a pas l'air d'être très utilisé.

> Mot peu souvent employé pour désigner une personne qui dispose de connaissances dans un domaine particulier du savoir ou qui a pu être témoin d'un fait matériel. ([dictionnaire-juridique.com](https://dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/sachant.php))

Le terme n'est pas récent, Alexandre Dumas compare d'ailleurs le substantif et le participe présent dans [le comte de monte-cristo](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Dumas_-_Le_Comte_de_Monte-Cristo_(1889)_Tome_1.djvu/245) :

> « il y a les sachants et les savants : c’est la mémoire qui fait les uns, c’est la philosophie qui fait les autres. »

Comment: Bonjour ! Merci. Pourquoi l'exemple suggère-t-il une utilisation différente au Canada si l'emploi colle avec la définition juridique pour la _personne qui dispose de connaissances dans un domaine_ ?

Comment: Bonjour, le remarque faisait référence à l'apsect connotation négative. J'ai édité pour être plus clair et j'ai complété.